# Why does my minimum function not print anything?

Tags: python, minimum

I cannot figure out why my code is not returning the minimum score:

```
def min_score(student):
    x = student[0]
    for i in student:
        if i < x:
            minimum = i
            i += 1
            print('Minimum score:', minimum)
            return minimum

brian = [input('Enter brians scores:')]
min_score(brian)
```

I tried adding `.split()` to the end of the input but that did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Your `input` statement requires few tweaks. Previously it was just a `list` of one `string`. What you need to do is `split` your numbers by `whitespace`, map each element to `int`  and then convert that to `list`.

```
brian = list(map(int,input('Enter brians scores:').split()))
```

And few changes in your function too are required.

```
def min_score(student):
    x_min = student[0]
    for ele in student[1:]:
        if ele < x_min:
            x_min = ele

    print('Minimum score:', x_min)
    return x_min
```

#driver values :

```
IN : Enter brians scores: 3 5 1
IN : brian = [3,5,1]
OUT : Minimum score: 1
```

---

But ofcourse, its far more easier to just use the `min` function on the list.

```
brian = list(map(int,input('Enter brians scores:').split()))
print('Minimum score:', min(brian))
```

Answer (score 1):

brian is a string. A string in python is a list of chars. With your for loop you go through each char in your string. You should split the string to get a list (of strings!). To evaluate the values you need to typecast each element of the list. Also there was a problem with your variables and you indentation. This works:

```
def min_score(student):
    minimum = int(student[0])
    for score in student:
        i = int(score)
        if i < minimum:
            minimum = i
    print('Minimum score:', minimum)
    return minimum

brian = input('Enter brians scores:').split()
min_score(brian)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. What is the purpose for adding: for score in student: i = int(score)?

Comment: I replaced the variable i with score in the loop and then use i to keep the integer value of the string in score. Remember that student contains a list of strings that you have to convert to int before you can compare them!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i assume the scores are comma separated when entered.

```
def min_score(student):

    x = student[0]
    print x
    for i in student:
        if i < x:
            x = i
    print('Minimum score:', x)
    return x

brian = input('Enter brians scores:')
min_score(brian)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kaushik's changes, you need to remove the line

```
i += 1
```

In a for loop, the i is already changed every time you go through the for loop. You also have to return minimum at the end of the for loop. If you return minimum as soon as you find a value lower than i, you would only find the **first** minimum value, not the minimum for the **entire** list.
The revised code would look like this:

```
def min_score(student):
    minimum = student[0]
    for i in student:
        if i < minimum:
            minimum = i
    return minimum

brian = list(map(int,input('Enter brians scores:')))
print min_score(brian)
```

If you put

```
 44,33,55
```

into the input, the function would return

```
33
```

accurately.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function is comparing the elements of the input list to `x`, but you assign to `minimum`.
2. With the `print` and `return` nested inside the `if`, you won't wait until you have the minimum of the entire list.
3. Don't increment `i`; it's a value out of your list, not an index.